# jQuery plugin for a popup/tooltip?

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup, tooltip

Can anyone point me to a jQuery plugin or solution to achieve this:

If for example I have a question mark, and when the user clicks on it, a small popup window will pop out from it and will give a information.

Right now I don't know any plugins like this, but I'm sure there should be alot of them.

Comment: google "jquery popup plugin"... example: http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jqBubblePopup

Comment: You can build your own popup and toggle it's visibility with javascript/jQuery. This is simple, so there is no need for a popup plugin.

Comment: Why not use the HTML `title=` attribute for hover information? no JS needed and great accessibility.

Comment: is there any chance to do a js onclick function, that if someone will click on that icon automatically the title text will be shown, or just when someone moves mouse over it, title will be shown without delay?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the [Tooltip](https://jqueryui.com/tooltip/) jQuery UI plugin.

I've also had success with [cluetip](http://plugins.learningjquery.com/cluetip/) in the past.

Note: I've also used qtip but when I went to the website the corporate anti-virus flagged it as a security risk so beware.